# How does this violate probability theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**Given:** $X = Y^2 + Z^2$ (hence $E[X] = E[Y^2] + E[Z^2]$)

$p(X = 1) = .52$, $p(X = 4) = .24$, $p(X = 16) = .24$
$p(Y = -1) = .5$, $p(Y = 3) = .5$

**Question:** Despite not being handed any information about $Z$, prove that this could never hold in classical probability theory.

Comment: $Y=3 \implies X > 1$, so $p(X = 1) \leq p(Y \neq 3)$

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you!